# If $m(A)=0$, does this imply that $m(\log(A)) = 0$ when $A\subset \mathbb{R}_{+}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, logarithms, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The question is as follows:
Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and let $\log(A)=\{\log(t): t\in A\}$.If $m(A)=0$,then is it true that $m(\log(A)) = 0$? If $m(A) < \infty$, then is it true that $m(A) < \infty$? Here $m$ refers to the Lebesgue measure.

For part (a), I think it is true.
\begin{align*}
m(\log(A)) &= \int 1_{\log(A)}(t) dt \\
&= \int 1_A(e^t) dt \\
&= \int \frac{1_A(u)}{u} du \\
&= \int_A \frac{1}{u} du = 0 
\end{align*}
since $m(A) =0$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Part (b) I think is false. My counterexample is the set

$$
A = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} (\frac{n}{2^n}, \frac{n+1}{2^n})
$$

which has $m(A) = 1$ but $m(\log(A)) = \infty$.

Comment: A locally Lipschitz function sends measure zero sets to measure zero sets. $C^1$ functions like logarithms are locally Lipschitz due to the mean-value theorem. So this gives you a more general theorem for next time.

Comment: Use `\{` and `\}` to get $\{$ and $\}$ in mathjax.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Maybe an easier example for b) would be to just consider $A = (0,1)$ or any other interval with $0$ as a left point.

Comment: Your argument for (a) is correct. same for (b).

Comment: Thank you all, that's really helpful. Dominik, I think you are right that is a much easier counterexample haha! peek-a-boo that is super helpful because at least it tells me whether it is true or not for any $f$. Thank you Mittens for confirming that it is correct.

Comment: Typo in second line.